# Table with kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, codeblocks, kable, kableextra

I want to make the table as in the picture using kableExtra.

[image]

I am trying to use the R code chunk below, but I get unexpected result. Could you please show me how to fix it?

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(
  Operator = c("`==`", "`!=`", "`>`", "`<`", "`>=`", "`<=`"),
  Interpretation = c("Equal to", "Not equal to", "Greater than", "Less than", "Greater than or equal to", "Less than or equal to")
)
df %>% kbl() %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c('striped', 'hover', 'condensed'))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Could be a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2279)..

Comment: I fixed it by replacing `Opterater = c("\`==\`", "\`!=\`", "<code>&gt;</code>", "<code>&lt;</code>", "<code>>=</code>", "<code><=</code>")` and `kbl(escape=F)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could do

```
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(
  Operator = c("==", "!=", ">", "<", ">=", "<="),
  Interpretation = c("Equal to", "Not equal to", "Greater than", "Less than", "Greater than or equal to", "Less than or equal to")
)

df %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_classic(full_width=F, html_font="Cambria") %>% 
  row_spec(0, bold=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the `Interpretation` column of your dataFrame. You can change the html_font if you want something closer to your example.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Is it possible to put the operators in code block like in my result above? If I replace <= by <- for example, the result does not look good without code block.

Comment: Sure, you can keep the code you used to create your dataFrame and the Operators will remain as a code block